# git - Blob/index file history

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to build the full history of file(s) in git and access the raw file content (as opposed to the diff).

In order to do this I was attempting to get the hash that is generated when a blob is staged in git, I can then use that hash to find the raw file content that was staged with git add.

I have found a way of getting the staged hashes by looking at the full 'raw' commit with
git log --raw.

However, this provides me with a bunch of information I don't need, such as the author,date,commit message. I would like to be able to get the filenames and hashes by themselves without all of the other information. Im able to use a regex to trim for the information I want, but was hoping for a solution that doesn't require trimming of any kind, im hoping that someone might have a git incantation for fetching this.

```
commit 0fef32119a00ca59b24686257fdd7e056c0bcb1a
Author: BenjaminWeber <benjamin.weber@bedarra.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 11 20:17:04 2016 +0000

commit message here

:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A  .deps
:000000 100644 0000000... 68af6a7... A  foo
:000000 100644 0000000... 2372199... A  bar
```

Comment: I'm aware of git ls-files -s <fileName> to get the hash for files that are currently staged, but I'd want the full stage history not just the current stage

Comment: This sounds intriguing but it's way unclear what you are trying to do.  "full stage history" ???

Comment: @andrewC I am trying to get the full **content** history of a file.

If I have a plain text file called 'foo', which I have modified over 3 commits, I would like to be able to get the full plaintext content of the file from each commit.

In order to accomplish this I was attempting to get the hash that was generated for 'foo' when it gets staged in git.

Comment: in that case just rev-list the file to get all the commit SHAs for it and then `git show` the specific one for each SHA.  Maybe edit your question because you don't really want the staging area anything, you want the committed version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax for referring files in old revisions described in `git help gitrevisions`:

```
<rev>:<path>, e.g. HEAD:README, :README, master:./README
   A suffix : followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given
   path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon.
```

You can get the relevant revision using `git rev-list` and use `git show <rev>:<path>` to show the content of the files at that point in time.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
for hash in $(git rev-list HEAD -- .gitignore); do
  echo $hash
  git show $hash:.gitignore;
done
```

This shows all Versions of `.gitignore` in the history of HEAD.